# Who am I? Try finding it out from the hints in the form of a 9 digit number

Tags: cipher

> Hi friends. I am **252116211**.  You may think I am **252116211** or
>   **252116211**. But I am not. Also, I am not **252116211**, **252116211**, **252116211**.... or some other **252116211**. There is a lot that's not what I am. I am lazy enough to list them all.  But one thing I can guarantee you,
>   *I am definitely **252116211***. If you know the old **bda**, who expanded his three member family to ten by inviting seven new members, with his help,
>   you can find me.

Tell me who I am and how did you find me (it will be appreciated if you can explain everything mentioned in the question).

Comment: Bomb Damage Assessment? British Dental Association?

Comment: @AE looking at numbers, big data analysis, broadcast data network sound more relevant

Answer (score 1):

Probably not right but...

> **112911252**, which is 252116211 rotated 180 degrees when typed in a calculator.

bda's family is

> **abdenmpquw**, which are letters that look like other letters when rotated 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

I would put this in a comment to the question, but that doesn't have spoiler tags. 
So my lead would be that it has to do..

> ...with the [Broadcast Driver Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd693015(v=vs.85).aspx)

, but I haven't figured out who you are yet. I believe this because

> IPs are about numbers

and

> "the old" may refer to the 'outdated' technology as mentioned in the linked article.

However. I do not know how to go further from here. Maybe some other geek can?

Comment: I tried using your second spoilered section to parse the 10 digit number above into a useful sequence.  Starting with 25 got me the UK's Ministry of Defense, and starting with 2 got me an Israeli cell service.  There are only 5 valid sequences in this series though, since 252 doesn't work (I think.)

Comment: British Defence Agency? Not really anything in Google bout it. It's probably top secret. Ooh a red dot...